# In Rails 6, how ensure a Mailer will not retry, eg, how add ActiveJob retry: false setting when Active job is used implicitly (not explicitly)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, rails-activejob

In a new Rails 6.1 app, I want to explicitly disable any retries for mail jobs.

Since ActionMailer *automatically* uses ActiveJob, how can I add custom ActiveJob configuration for a specific mailer class, such as disabling sidekiq retries?

If there was an *explicit* ActiveJob class being used, it's easy:

```
class ExampleJob < ActiveJob::Base
  sidekiq_options retry: false # custom setting allowed here in a JOB

  def perform(*args)
    # Perform Job
  end
end
```

But in the case like ActionMailer where ActiveJob is used *implicitly* ("behind the curtain") how does one explicitly disable sidekiq retries for a mail job?

For example, when sending an email like this:

```
AccountInvitationsMailer.with(account_invitation: self).invite.deliver_later
```

when the current mailer code is:

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "someone@example.com"
  layout "mailer"

  # Include any view helpers from your main app to use in mailers here
  helper ApplicationHelper
end


class AccountInvitationsMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def invite
    @account_invitation = params[:account_invitation]
    @account = @account_invitation.account
    @invited_by = @account_invitation.invited_by

    name = @account_invitation.name
    email = @account_invitation.email

    mail(
      to: "#{name} <#{email}>",
      from: "#{@invited_by.name} <invites@example.com>",
      subject: t(".subject", inviter: @invited_by.name, account: @account.name)
    )
  end
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually you can explicitly set which ActiveJob class to bee used on ActionMailer like:

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  self.delivery_job = ExampleJob

  # blah blah blah
end
```

So you can set anything else later within the ActiveJob class.

Comment: Wow. Very, very, curious, how did you KNOW this? Seriously. delivery_job is not even mentioned in the Rails ActionMailer guide, and even now, KNOWING what to look for, I find maybe 3 articles. It's IMO an essential feature of ActionMailer but basically no one talks about it.

Comment: @jpw the core team are very happy to accept documentation PRs if you feel it's lacking

Comment: @jpw stumbled upon this page few months ago when I had the same need. https://bigbinary.com/blog/rails-5-2-allows-mailers-to-use-custom-active-job-class

Comment: @blackbiron your google-fu is much better than mine, that is a small undocumented needle in the internet haystack! So I had to actually ask. Thanks for that quick reply! ;)

Answer (score 2):

In case someone sees this for Rails version >= 6 (tested also in 7), here's a more detailed implementation for `ExampleJob`.

Considering the example above and a call like:

```rb
AccountInvitationsMailer.with(some: 'params').invite.deliver_later
```

The `ExampleJob` class should look something like:

```rb
class ExampleJob < ApplicationJob
  # rescue_from StandardError, with: :notify_to_exception_tracker
  # Any other customization option

  # Perform will receive 4 params
  # mailer: The original mailer class, i.e. `AccountInvitationsMailer`
  # mailer_method: The method called in the mailer, i.e. `invite`
  # delivery_method: The delivery method used, i.e. `deliver_later`
  # args: Original arguments sent to the mailer wrapped in params container, i.e. `{ params: { some: 'params' } }`
  def perform(mailer, mail_method, delivery_method, args)
    klass = mailer.constantize
    klass.with(args[:params]).public_send(mail_method).send(delivery_method)
  end

  # ...
end
```

Finally, another alternative to the original question, is to just ignore delivery errors by setting `config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false` in the relevant environment file (development, staging, production, etc.)

Comment: I'm confused, so how do I pass something like this to a mailer? < sidekiq_options queue: :cron, retry: 3, backtrace: true, lock: :until_executed